# Не могу настроить Selenide и Appium для IOS

Tags: java, ios, appium, selenide

Образец взятый с репозитория Selenide работать не захотел
[image]

При инициализации AppiumDriver на эмуляторе запускается приложение, так что не получается только передать команды Selenide в Appium.

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class CustomMobileDriver {

    AppiumDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void getIosDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformName", "iOS");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "iPhone 11");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "14.1");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("automationName", "XCUITest");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability("app", "/Users/alekseigerasimov/1/UIKitCatalog.app");
        URL remoteUrl = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
        driver = new AppiumDriver(remoteUrl, desiredCapabilities);
    }
}



Тест падает с ошибкой: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create WebDriver of type io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver

С такой конфигурацией браузера "Configuration.browser = AppiumDriver.class.getName();" тоже ошибка:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create WebDriver of type io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver


import com.codeborne.selenide.Configuration;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.closeWebDriver;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open;

public class IosTest extends CustomMobileDriver {
    public Page page = new Page();

    @Before
    public void before() {
        closeWebDriver();
        Configuration.browserSize = null;
        Configuration.browser = IOSDriver.class.getName();
        open();
    }

    @Test
    public void test () {
        page.buttonPageControl.click();
    }
}
```

Использую 2 зависимости:

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>junit</groupId>
     <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
     <version>4.13.2</version>
     <scope>IosTest</scope>
 </dependency>
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
     <artifactId>selenide-appium</artifactId>
     <version>2.0.3</version>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>
```

Вопросы:
1.Как передать команды Selenide в Appium?

2.Что нужно передать в эту конфигурацию?
Configuration.browser = IOSDriver.class.getName();
Сейчас передается: "io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver"

Answer (score 0):

This is working case:

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.WebDriverProvider;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.ios.options.XCUITestOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.Capabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import javax.annotation.CheckReturnValue;
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import javax.annotation.ParametersAreNonnullByDefault;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

@ParametersAreNonnullByDefault
public class IOSDriverProvider implements WebDriverProvider {
    @Override
    @CheckReturnValue
    @Nonnull
    public WebDriver createDriver(Capabilities capabilities) {

        XCUITestOptions options = new XCUITestOptions();
        options.merge(capabilities);
        options.setAutomationName("XCUITest");
        options.setPlatformName("iOS");
        options.setDeviceName("iPhone 11");
        options.setPlatformVersion("14.1");
        options.setApp("/Users/alekseigerasimov/1/UIKitCatalog.app");

        try {
            return new IOSDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), options);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
} 


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Android_Ios_Selenide</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>18</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>18</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>IosTest</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide-appium</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
                    <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).